# How to get random array from multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get random array:

for example:

```
$navItems= array(

    array(
        slug    => "top10.php",
        title   => "Top 10 geriausi"
    ),
    array(
        slug    => "index.php",
        title   => "Pagrindinis"
    ),
    array(
        slug    => "top-prasciausi.php",
        title   => "Top 10 prasciausi"
    ),
    array(
        slug    => "visi-politikai.php",
        title   => "Visi politiki"
    ),
);
```

and after that use this random array inside foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($navItems as $item) {
    echo "<li class=\"hov\"><a href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a><li>";
}
```

Instead of `$navItems` variable i want to use that random arrays from `$navItems` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shuffle` to randomize the array

**Note:** If you are trying to pick one from the array, you can use `shuffle` and select the first element of the array.

```
$navItems = array(
  array(
        'slug'    => "top10.php",
        'title'   => "Top 10 geriausi"
  ),
  array(
        'slug'    => "index.php",
        'title'   => "Pagrindinis"
  ),
  array(
        'slug'    => "top-prasciausi.php",
        'title'   => "Top 10 prasciausi"
  ),
  array(
        'slug'    => "visi-politikai.php",
        'title'   => "Visi politiki"
  ),
);

shuffle( $navItems );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $navItems );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to *something* like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slug] => index.php
            [title] => Pagrindinis
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [slug] => visi-politikai.php
            [title] => Visi politiki
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [slug] => top10.php
            [title] => Top 10 geriausi
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [slug] => top-prasciausi.php
            [title] => Top 10 prasciausi
        )

)
```

Doc: [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: Thank you that works, I made mistake trying to shuffle it in foreach loop :)

Comment: Happy to help @JonasTamoševičius